# I am not able to select an AVD device in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, avd-manager

For some reason, I am unable to select a virtual device in Android studio. When I hover over the drop down menu to select a device, it says that this device is "not applicable" for the project that I am trying to run, but I have emmulated the project on this device before. There is also a little purple icon next to the device name that I am unsure of the meaning. Any idea of what the issue might be?

[Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFgzA.png)

Comment: Put left field in app option which has Android logo

Comment: Looks like you are not trying to run the app. Instead you are running a gradle file which cannot run in emulator. What you should see is a green robot instead of an elephant. http://prntscr.com/rvundn
Finally, the little purple icon means that the emulator is not running. When you run it, it will turn into green!

Comment: Thank you for the input. However, I am not able to select a module under the app (green robot) configuration. I am able to see the module when I open the module settings, but it does not show up in the module drop down menu in the app configuration. Any ideas why it isnt showing up?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to run the project,instead of the app itself.
Click on the **Select Run/Debug Configuration**, and select the APP option instead the project name.